# Is -&gt; equivalentto -> in erlang?

Tags: syntax, erlang

I came across this piece of code in erlang examples and I don't seem to get it.

```
hello(_E,_I) -&gt;
    "Text: Hello\r\n\r\n".
```

Why is it not written like this?

```
hello(_E,_I) ->
    "Text: Hello\r\n\r\n".
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

No, they are not equivalent.  It should be "->".

So why is it like that?  The

```
&gt;
```

is how one represents ">" when writing HTML, so what you are seeing is a typographical oversight on part of the editor.

I recommend you mention the problem to that website's editorial staff. :)